# Javascript: setting variable to nodeValue not working

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm having trouble setting a variable and can't find any helpful documentation.

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body onload="alert(document.getElementById('foo').firstChild.nodeValue)">
  <a id="foo" href="old">Foobar</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

But this does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var theText = document.getElementById('foo').firstChild.nodeValue ;
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="alert(theText)">
  <a id="foo" href="old">Foobar</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

The alert says "undefined". What I really want to do is something like this, which also does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var theElement = document.getElementById('foo') ;
    var theText = theElement.firstChild.nodeValue ;
    document.write(theElement.getAttribute('href')) ;
    theElement.setAttribute('href', theText) ;
    document.write(meta.getAttribute('href')) ;
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a id="foo" href="old">Foobar</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your script runs, the `foo` element doesn't exist. If you check the JavaScript console you should see an error, along the lines of this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

You get this error because `getElementById` will return `null` if the element you're looking for isn't found.

You need to execute the JavaScript code after the markup. Move your `script` tag to the bottom of the `body`, or put it in a DOM ready/load event handler. For example:

```
<body onload="alert(theText)">
    <a id="foo" href="old">Foobar</a>
    <!-- Now the `foo` element actually exists, our script can find it -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var theText = document.getElementById('foo').firstChild.nodeValue;
    </script>
</body>
```